# Call the right child class based on a value

Tags: java, class, inheritance, parent-child, super

I need to establish a 2-level hierarchy of classes in my lambda to handle the incoming SQS event.
The event can be of the following hierarchy :

1. SQSEvent from Queue1
   a. EventType 1
   b. EventType 2
   c. EventType 3
2. SQSEvent from Queue2
   a. Event type x
   b. Event type y

From the main lambda handler I want to invoke either `Queue1Handler.class` or `Queue2Handler.class` using maybe a `MapBinder` <"queue arn", className.class>.

Now I can create and inject 2 more `MapBinder` <"evnetType", className.class> in `Queue1Handler.class` or `Queue2Handler.class` respectively and I want either class to invoke the right child class (`EventType1Handler.class`, `EventType2Handler.class`, `EventType3Handler.class` / `EventTypeXHandler.class`, `EventTypeYHandler.class`) by analyzing the event type (parsing the SQS message in their own unique logic).

What I want is to create some "templating" (say using Abstract classes) so that a method `process()` is imposed to be implemented by the child classes (Event Type Classes).

If I am keeping Queue1Handler/Queue2Handler abstract or interface I cannot instantiate it. What is the best way to create these classes while also conveying the said hierarchy.

Comment: Any code that you can share for us to understand what you are trying to do in code?

Comment: I don't really have a code since I am trying to establish class hierarchy. But this is the idea, not sure how to make it happen. The hierarchy and the flow sequence needed is what I have mentioned..

Comment: Have you looked at an AbstractFactory or a strategy pattern?